# Counting how many times a specific checked value occurs in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, input, radio-button

I have some input radio buttons that can have the the following values : "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" and "F"

I want to count how many times each value was checked.

I'm not sure how to do this in AngularJS but I tried using jQuery like this `$("#test").find("input:checked").val();` but I only get the value from the first input.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="QuizController as quiz" class="form-group row">
    <div id="test" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
        <form ng-repeat="question in quiz.questions" role="form" class="form-orizontal" novalidate>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="{{question.Value1}}" name="{{question.Index}}">
                {{question.Question1}}
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="{{question.Value2}}" name="{{question.Index}}">
                {{question.Question2}}
            </label>
            <hr>
        </form>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Arată-mi profilul meu</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('MotivationalApp', []);

    app.controller('QuizController', function(){
        this.questions = quiz
    });

    var quiz = [{
        Index: 1,
        Question1: "I'm a developer",
        Value1: "A",
        Question2: "I'm a tester",
        Value2: "B",
    },
    {
        Index: 2,
        Question1: "I'm happy",
        Value1: "C",
        Question2: "I'm sad",
        Value2: "D",
    }]
})();
```

Can anyone give some help with this. Any hint is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in another way

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="checkedItems.value1" value="{{question.Value1}}" name="{{question.Index}}">
...
```

**ng-model="checkedItems.value1"**

And in controller you can loop thought this object(checkedItems) and count how many items are checked

```
for(var key in $scope.checkedItems){
    var value = $scope.checkedItems[key];
    ...
}
```